# OpenStack additional compute node set up questions

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, devstack

This is my first time setting up an OpenStack instance on Ubuntu and I'm having some difficulty with setting up additional compute nodes. I've set up a controller node following the devstack instructions [here](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/xena/) with the stable/xena release and I'm trying to add an additional compute node so I've gone through the set up [here](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/xena/install/compute-install-ubuntu.html) but I have a few questions.

1. The additional compute node does not show up as a hypervisor (although it shows up under the compute service list), does someone have a resource for how to add the compute node as a hypervisor?
2. I ran the `discover_hosts` tool within the devstack repo so that the compute node gets picked up by the db but what transport url and database connections should the additional compute node use? Do I copy the transport url and database connection url used by the controller node?
3. Does Openstack use the resources (storage, RAM, cpus) of the additional compute node to create new VMs as well?

If someone could provide advice on how to go about setting up this compute node that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**Note**: In the comments below I mention some steps I tried so I'll just sum them up here with their results.

`nova-manage cell_v2 discover_hosts --verbose` gave this output:

```
Found 3 cell mappings. 
Skipping cell0 since it does not contain hosts. Getting computes from cell 'cell1': <random_string1> . 
Found 0 unmapped computes in cell <random_string1>. 
Getting computes from cell: <random_string2>. 
Checking host mapping for compute host 'vmname': <random_string3>. 
Found 0 unmapped computes in cell <random_string2>
```

So the command runs but I think theres an issue with how things are set up in the db since the compute node doesn't seem to be linked to a cell.

`nova-manage cell_v2 list_hosts` output gives 2 hosts, the controller and the vm I am trying to add but the cell name for the compute node I'm trying to add is None.

`nova-manage cell_v2 list_cells` output gives 3 cells, one with no `name` value but it has the same cell uuid as <random_string2> in the above comment with a transport url that has no `/nova_cell1` ending and the db connection string is the same as cell0.

So I think there is an issue with how the compute node is trying to be added to the db?

Answer (score 0):

1, try run `nova-manage cell_v2 discover_hosts` in **controller node** to discover hypervisor.

2, you should not do anything if the step 1 works.

3, yes if the step 1 works.

Comment: So I'm able to run that and this is the output:

 ```Found 3 cell mappings. Skipping cell0 since it does not contain hosts. Getting computes from cell 'cell1': <random_string1> . Found 0 unmapped computes in cell <random_string1>. Getting computes from cell: <random_string2>. Checking host mapping for compute host 'vmname': <random_string3>. Found 0 unmapped computes in cell <random_string2>```

So the command runs but I think theres an issue with how things are set up in the db.

Comment: When I run a ```nova-manage cell_v2 list_hosts``` I get 2 hosts, the controller and the vm I am trying to add but the cell name for the compute node I'm trying to add is ```None```. Also if I run ```nova-manage cell_v2 list_cells``` there is a 3rd cell with no name matching <random_string2> in the above comment with a transport url that has no ```/nova_cell1``` ending and the db connection string is the same as ```cell0```. This doesn't seem right to me .

Comment: Could you remove the new compute node and `discover_hosts` first without modify the database data by manual? Maybe `This is because the compute node for that host in that cell is not deleted and since it was mapped once`, see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/+bug/1735719

Comment: When you say remove the new compute node, do you mean remove the host & it's related cell from the ```cell_v2```? I've tried doing that but then the ```nova-manage cell_v2 discover_hosts --verbose``` command doesn't discover anything (as if there are no hosts to discover even though the compute node should be discoverable)

Comment: what's the result of `openstack resource provider list`?